# MySQL Query vs Procedure Issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Alright, this one's got me baffled...

The following query, by itself runs perfectly:

```
Select `LongTitle`, `Keywords`, `Description`, `templateID`, `Content`
From `Content`
Where 
  `Published` = 1
AND
  ((`siteID` = SiteID) AND (`LinkAlias` = Alias))
```

When I set `SiteID` to 24 and `Alias` to '', but when I attempt to get the records with this in a Stored Procedure, it returns returns a record (that should be only for SiteID 24, if I switch it to SiteID 25

What gives?

Comment: running a query inside a sproc should not return any different results than running it by itself outside of a sproc

Comment: I understand that Marc, thanks for pointing that out...    this is why I asked a question here...

Comment: Wish I could post screen shots.  Executing the same procedure with 2 different values for `SiteID` produces the exact same results... 1 record... mind you, there are only records for 1 `SiteID`.  Somehow it seems like the Sproc is completely ignoring the `SiteID` parameter...

Comment: I get the same results when removing the `Published` and `LinkAlias` as well...

Comment: Fixed it...  it's because my `SiteID` parameter is the same name as the field I am checking against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it... it's because my `SiteID` parameter is the same name as the field I am checking against